# Zooming in/out a UIView by a button iPhone

Tags: ios4

Hi all I need to zoon in and out a UIView by a button/segmented controll  as seen below.

[image] Is that possible without using scroll view?Pleae help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the view's [`transform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform). In particular [`CGAffineTransformMakeScale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale) will probably be useful to you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it ??wat to write in the button acotins if i have a UIView *myView and a UIButton *btn??

Comment: @Sadumerry: for example, `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);`

Answer (score 0):

The ABOVE code is actually right!! But Here I am Just elaborating it..as what i have used..

-(IBAction)zoomin:(id)sender{

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5,.5);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
//self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}
-(IBAction)zoomout:(id)sender{

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
//self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}